# Mapping interface instead of class to Database Table

Tags: database, class, linq-to-sql, interface

Is this possible? how?

As far as you know to mapping a class to db table we should be use `TableAttribute(Name="tableName")` attribute, so we can't use attributes on interfaces. If I don't use this attribute:

> "The type 'interfaceName' is not mapped as a Table."

showed.

Comment: This is where EF4 knocks down L2SQL. You can map tables to abtract classes, and it fully supports inheritance. Entity Framework 4 FTW.

Comment: i think you're misunderstood my question! i want to map database tables to interfaces! no classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

Refer to [TableAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx) on MSDN.

> **TableAttribute** - Designates a **class** as an entity class that is associated
>   with a database table.